# Rendering webpage as H.264

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, chromium-embedded, video-encoding

I'm trying to render HTML as a H.264 stream, and then streaming it to another PC on my network.

I've got the last part, `streaming to to another PC on my network` down.
Now my only problem is rendering the webpage.

I can't render it once, because it isn't a static webpage.
I need to load the webpage, fetch images, run javascript and open websockets.

The only way I can imagine this working, is if I run a browser (or maybe something like [CEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework)?), and "capture" the output, and render it as H.264

I'm basically trying to do the same as OBS' BrowserSource, but the only reason I'm NOT using OBS, is because I can't find a good way to run it headless.

**NOTE:** I need to be able to do it through the commandline, completely headless.

Comment: Have you considered headless Chrome? I haven't tried streaming video, but it seems like something you could get Chrome to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050259/headless-chrome-capture-screen-video-or-animation

Comment: did you check webRTC ?

Comment: @Redanium I did not (and have of course now). But I have to stream h.264 via RTC.

Comment: @Sidney Headless Chrome is useless for anything media.  Sadly, they've broken it.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this with the Chromium Tab Capture API, and the Off-Screen Tab Capture API.

Chromium will conveniently handle all the rendering, including bringing in WebGL rendered stuff, and composite all together in a nice neat MediaStream for you.  From there, you can use it in a WebRTC call or pass off to a MediaRecorder instance.

The off-screen tab capture even has a nice separate isolated process that cannot access local cameras and such.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture

Comment: I should probably note that I need to do this headless. (Have added to question)