# Recording headless chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome-headless

I currently have some UI tests running in Jenkins using headless Chrome.
I am able to take screenshots but I was wondering how I could record videos from my testruns.

I read that xvfb is a possibility but since headless chrome is available, I was wondering if it would be possible to do this via devtools itself or some Java library.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: did you consider this option ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050259/headless-chrome-capture-screen-video-or-animation

Comment: I did read that post before but it looks way too heavy to be handling each frame individually.

Comment: agree with you, but if you really need to have video recording looks like it is one of the ways, cause as Im aware of chrome headless do not have options to record vide recordings

Comment: @Homewrecker were you able to find a solution for this? If yes, please share. Thanks

Comment: @kvm006 nope, abandoned the idea

Comment: @Homewrecker you can use [selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_video_recording) . but you will need to change your selenium integration to a Docker one..